# Format a string into a specific format

Tags: java, string

Currently i have a 9 String number

```
String s = 123456789
```

how can i convert this string into this kind of format?

```
String newS = 12 - 34 - 5678 - 9
```

Comment: which is an algorithm you want to use? What do you want the output format to be? 2 - 2 - 4 - 1 characters?

Comment: are you considering strings of size 9 only? Otherwise please mention the format in which such strings should be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will help you.

```
public static String formatString(String str) {
    return str.substring(0, 1) + " - " + str.substring(2, 3) + " - " + str.substring(4, 7) + " - " + str.substring(8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java8 streams you can get a cleaner version...

```
String s = "123456789";

AtomicInteger pos = new AtomicInteger();
String newS = IntStream.of(2, 2, 4, 1)
      .mapToObj(n -> s.substring(pos.getAndAdd(n), pos.get()))
      .collect(Collectors.joining(" - "));
```

Comment: notice IntStream.of(2, 2, 4, 1)  -- and joining(" - ") . ... so easily customisable without extra effort...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
    String s = "123456789";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})(\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    String formatted = matcher.find() ?
            matcher.group(1) + " - " + matcher.group(2) + " - " + matcher.group(3) + " - " + matcher.group(4) :
            "";
    System.out.println(formatted); // 12 - 34 - 5678 - 9
```